# ¿Alguien sabe porqué esos archivos se ponen en rojo? estoy usando el jdk 21 y spring 3.1.4 pero no sé que es

Tags: java, spring-boot, git, spring, github

[image: Errores al iniciar proyecto en Itellij IDEA con spring boot archivos no reconocidos]
Errores al iniciar proyecto en Itellij IDEA con spring boot archivos no reconocidos

Comment: En Intellij los ficheros en rojo suelen ser los que no se han añadido a la herramienta de control de versiones, parece que git en tu caso. Seguramente esos ficheros tampoco estén en el .gitignore.

Comment: Muchas gracias.